# Prove that if f(x) is integrable, then so is e^(f(x)).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integral-inequality

So here is my question:

I'm working on a homework problem that deals with Jensen's Inequality. It is a rather simple application, I believe, but I'm a little stuck. Here is the problem, along with my work.

Let $f$ be integrable over $[0,1]$. Show that

$\exp\left[\int_0^1 f(x) dx \right] \leq \int_0^1\exp[f(x)]dx$

On the surface, this appeared like a simple application of Jensen's Inequality, since $\phi (x) = e^x$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$. We know that $f$ is integrable, but it remains to show that $\exp[f(x)]$ is integrable. I know that the composition ($\exp[f(x)]$) is measureable, but I don't feel like that is enough to conclude that it is integrable.

Comment: Do you -- need -- $\exp[f(x)]$ to be integrable? I don't think this is required in the statement of Jensen's. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form

Comment: See, I read this also, but it contradicts the definition in my Real Analysis text, so I wasn't sure which to use :(

Comment: The integral of $e^{f(x)}$ is well defined since $e^{f(x)}$ is a positive function. So, even if its integral is $+\infty$ Jensen inequality still holds.
$$
$$
But are you rather asking whether $e^f$ has finite integral provided $f$ has finite integral?

Comment: Being finite is not a requirement :) Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

$\exp(f(x))$ is a nonnegative measurable function, so the worst thing that could happen is that the integral is $+\infty$.
And this is indeed possible: Let $f(x)=n$ if $\frac 1{n}-\frac1{n^3}<x<\frac1n$ with $n>1$ (and $0$ otherwise). Then $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6-1$$ whereas
$$ \int_0^1 \exp{f(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{e^n}{n^3}$$
is infinite ($e^n>n^3$ for $n$ suficiently big).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can prove $e^{f(x)}$ is integrable just because $f(x)$ is.  But it is OK, because if $e^{f(x)}$ is not integrable, then the right hand side is infinite, and the statement is obviously true.

To find a counterexample, look for functions of the form
$$ f(x) = 2^{\alpha k} \text{ if $x \in (2^{-k+1},2^{-k}]$} .$$
If $0 \le \alpha < 1$, then this is easily seen to be integrable.